# Minecraft /testfor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My question is simple, How do I test for at least 2 items in an inventory.

I don't want to test for exactly 2, I want at least two, so they have the ability to have more in their inventory and still get the result.

I have made this code but it doesn't work, it doesn't even give me an error:

```
testfor @a[score_craft_min=1] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:stick",Count:>1b}]}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I have worked on it and I'm not really sure on how to do it. But the command is: testfor @a[score_craft_min=1] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:stick",Count:>1b}]} that is what I have got so far

Comment: So show us what you've tried.  That will help quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CommandStats to obtain the number of items in the inventory as a scoreboard value, without being restricted to a single slot.

**Prerequisites:**

Objectives to hold the value.

```
/scoreboard objectives add StickCount dummy
/scoreboard objectives add IronCount dummy
```

In order for CommandStats to modify a score, the target must be tracked prior. This may need to run on a clock in the event new players can join at any time.

```
/scoreboard players add @a StickCount 0
/scoreboard players add @a IronCount 0
```

**Detection:**

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Apply the necessary AffectedItems trigger such that the player modifies their `StickCount` score.

   ```
   /stats entity @a set AffectedItems @a[c=1] StickCount
   ```
2. Cause players to run a /clear command, targeting themselves. While it does not remove any item, this causes their `StickCount` score to be set equal to the items that *could* have been cleared, which is equal to the number of sticks they had.

   ```
   /execute @a ~ ~ ~ clear @a[c=1] minecraft:stick 0 0
   ```
3. For other items, you repeat #1 and #2.

   ```
   /stats entity @a set AffectedItems @a[c=1] IronCount
   /execute @a ~ ~ ~ clear @a[c=1] minecraft:iron_ingot 0 0
   ```
4. You can then run commands targeting players based on their score. For example, the following says the name of players who had 2 or more sticks and iron ingots anywhere in their inventory (including spread across 2 separate stacks).

   ```
   /say @a[score_StickCount_min=2,score_IronCount_min=2] had 2 or more sticks & iron ingots.
   ```

Comment: could I set this to multiple items? Because I'm trying to make a structure which takes 2 iron ingots and 2 sticks to make a "Hammer"

Comment: @Hydrotronics You can, yes. You can have a secondary objective and integrate the /stats command into "detection", such that the target objective switches before running the next /clear command.

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with the /stats command, so how would I do this?

Comment: @Hydrotronics I've updated the answer to include the use of multiple items.

Comment: ok so I have done this and I have 3 sticks in my inventory, but the machine only picks up the 2 iron I have

Comment: @Hydrotronics It works fine for me. Make sure you are using the correct objective names and they are running in the correct order, such as by using 1.9's Chain command blocks.

Comment: i'm currently in 1.8.9 :p

Comment: @Hydrotronics Then you must rely on generic activation order as the mechanism will still work in 1.8. See [here](http://testfordev.com/update-order-fill-propagation/) for information concerning update order.